# Alternative to Von Mises distribution?

Tags: fitting, von-mises-distribution

I'm in the middle of a replication project in some previous studies using another stimulus space than these previous studies.

I want to test whether the estimation was made based on one or the other standard.

In the previous studies, researchers utilized Von Mises distribution to fit their data for their sets of data came from a circular set. Specifically, participants made responses on a circular dimension. They were asked to estimate a value in [0, 2$\pi$] and tested whether these people made their estimation based on two standards, call it $s_1$ and $s_2$. To test which one is the standard they used, the authors computed error for each standard, for example,

$e_1=$ (response) - $s_1$; and

$e_2=$ (response) - $s_2$.

And they fitted these two response errors to the von Mises distribution, for the responses were made on a circular dimension [0,$2\pi$]. Then they compared the two estimated $\kappa$s as the sensitivities of the responses. The results indicated that $\kappa$ of $e_1$ was significantly larger than that of $e_2$, and they concluded that people utilized $s_1$ as their estimation standard rather than $s_2$.

And now, I use a linear data set where participants responded on a scale of 0 to 100 [0,100]. I wish to do some similar analysis as they did. The problem is that the Gaussian distribution is not practical for this purpose since the estimated standard deviations are nearly identical for my data. Also, there is no significant difference in sample standard deviation even in the previous data.

I did try some other distributions, like truncated normal and lognormal after log-transformed (with the absolute errors). But the results were not desirable.

So, my question is: Is there any recommendable distribution alternative to the von Mises distribution on a linear scale other than the Gaussian?

Comment: There's not enough information here to permit objective answers.  It's quite unclear what the problem with the sample standard deviations might be, one one thing suggested by your description is that a response with a limited scale often needs an analysis with a generalized linear model rather than an ordinary least squares model.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your considerate comments on my silly question. I added some details to my question. Would you mind reviewing my edited question again?